# Controling link behaviours in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Ok so any help here would be great

I have a HTML page with an I frame loading a site of mine in it…

What I need to do is check in the iframe from the main document, the target attribute of a link and if it's blank, hijack it and add my own custom functionality from outside of the iframe in the main HTML document

The issue I have is the site being loaded in to the frame is on a different domain so I am not sure if this can be done? I have full control of the site been loaded in to the I frame so is there something in there I can set to allow it?

What I effectively want to do is hijack the links in an iframe which I guess could be an issue?

Can this be done, alternately does anyone know a way I could achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: If you can edit the code of the site being loaded by the iframe, you can call javascript methods from the iframe page to the page containing the iframe using `parent.method()`

Comment: Wow thank you, great idea! I am hearing lots about document.domain = "my domain.com" which fools the browser in to thinking they are on the same domain, then I could do something like... 
  
            var myIFrame = document.getElementById("iframe");
            var links = myIFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a");  do you have any experience of this?